# How do I set a child list item to be a different height from a parent list item in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a nav element that uses an unordered list.  Some of the list items will have a child div, containing its own unordered list, to act as a sub navigation.  My question is, I have the parent list items to be a certain height, but I want the sub-nav list item to have a dynamic height.  What it's doing, though is setting all list items to the parent styling.  How do I fix this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emvdct6L/)

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="main">
            <header>
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainnav">
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Studios
                            <div class="dropdownnav hidden">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Web Design &amp; Development</li>
                                    <li>Graphic Design</li>
                                    <li>Game Design &amp; Development</li>
                                    <li>Game Production</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>Meet the Team
                            <div class="dropdownnav hidden">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Team 1</li>
                                    <li>Team 2</li>
                                    <li>Team 3</li>
                                    <li>Team 4</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>Contact Us</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <article>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media(max-width: 1280px){
    html{
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}

section{
    margin-top: 1%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
}

header{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    height: 75px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

header, article{
    width: 100%;
}

nav{
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mainnav{
    list-style: none;
}

.mainnav li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1%;
    padding: 0.75%;
    width: 20%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(123, 3, 3);
}

.mainnav li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

div.dropdownnav{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 5;
}

div.dropdownnav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.dropdownnav li{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 95%;
    border: none;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.showing{
    display: block;
}

#main{
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

#logo{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/aimlogo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = (function(){
    let mainNav = document.getElementsByClassName("mainnav");
    let mainNavElement = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    let hiddenClass = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
    console.log(this.innerWidth);
    for(let i = 0; i < mainNavElement.length; i++){
        mainNavElement[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            console.log(i);
            let dropDownNav = this.getElementsByClassName("dropdownnav")[0];
            if(dropDownNav.classList.contains("hidden")){
                dropDownNav.classList.remove("hidden");
                dropDownNav.classList.add("showing");
            }
            else{
                dropDownNav.classList.remove("showing");
                dropDownNav.classList.add("hidden");
            }
            let dropDownNavElement = this.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(let j = 0; j < dropDownNavElement.length; j++){
                console.log(dropDownNavElement[j]);
            }
        })
        mainNavElement[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            let dropDownNav = this.getElementsByClassName("dropdownnav")[0];
            if(dropDownNav.classList.contains("showing")){
                dropDownNav.classList.remove("showing");
                dropDownNav.classList.add("hidden");
            }
        })
    }
})
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS rules with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

For example something like this:

```
div.dropdownnav li { height: 20px }
```

would affect only the sub-nav list items.

Comment: Unfortunately the list elements in the sub navigation division are still using the parent nav rules.  I've updated my question.

Comment: @Robert my answer still applies. Try giving a height to `div.dropdownnav li`.

Comment: Indeed it does, wasn't paying attention.  What if I want them to be a certain height if they have more than one line of text?

Comment: @Robert you could add a class to those `li` elements. E.g. `li.longtext`